# Java: How can I use this if-else statement (in constructor)?

Tags: java

I'd like to print out the name of the country and it's classification (as seen in the end of the code). However, the if-statement doesn't work. I tried putting it out of the constructor, but that doesn't work and when I try it in my main method it won't work anyway, because the variables are defined in the class Country. So I wanted to ask, how I can use this if statement to make the classification.

```
public class Exercise {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Country Sweden = new Country("Sweden", 498000000000l,10000000);
    Sweden.representcountry();
}

public static class Country{
    String name;
    long GDP;
    int population;
    int GDPCapita;

    String classification;

    public Country(String name, long GDP, int population){
        this.name = name;
        this.GDP = GDP;
        this.population = population;
        GDPCapita = (int) (this.GDP / this.population);
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    /*
     if(GDPCapita >= 10000){
        classification = "Developed country";
    }
    else {
        classification = "Developing country";
    }
    */


    final String END_OF_LINE = System.lineSeparator();
    public String representcountry(){
        System.out.println(this.name + ":" + END_OF_LINE // + classification
                + "Population: "  +  + this.population + END_OF_LINE
                + "GDP: " + this.GDP + END_OF_LINE
                + GDPCapita + " per capita");
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? Because pitting the `if...else` statement in the constructor, after GDPCaptia is calculated, should be fine.

Comment: This is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202672/if-else-statements-inside-a-java-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just do like this :

```
public Country(String name, long GDP, int population){
    this.name = name;
    this.GDP = GDP;
    this.population = population;
    GDPCapita = (int) (this.GDP / this.population);
    if(GDPCapita >= 10000){
        classification = "Developed country";
    }else {
        classification = "Developing country";
    }
}
```

---

By using ternary operator you can replace the if/else, he is shorter, but you need to understand and like it, this is only a tip :

```
classification = GDPCapita >= 10000 ? "Developed country" : "Developing country";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use everywhere the keyword "this." except for GDPCapita and classification ?

```
public Country(String name, long GDP, int population){
// Getters and Setters

    this.name = name;
    this.GDP = GDP;
    this.population = population;
    this.GDPCapita = (int) (this.GDP / this.population);
    if(this.GDPCapita >= 10000){
        this.classification = "Developed country";
    }
    else {
        this.classification = "Developing country";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say you don't need a separate member variable for classification at all.  Better to have a getter that derives the value from GPDCapita.  No need for a setter.